# How to update pod homepage (readme) on Cocoapods.org website

Tags: ios, cocoapods

We have a released pod and I want to update the readme on the  pod homepage on Cocoapods.
I tried to update the readme parameter in the podspec file to read from a file in the framework zip file but still not reflecting on Cocoapods website.

```
spec.readme       = 'AATKit/AATKit.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/AATKit.framework/README.md'
```

Does anyone know how to update the pod's homepage on Cocoapods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [Podspec Reference](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#tab_readme), it describes the `readme` entry as *“The **URL** for the README markdown file for this pod version.”*  In your code sample, you seem to have a repo-relative filepath, not an Internet-accessible URL.  *(Don't ask me why it works like this, I have disagreed with many of CocoaPods' design decisions over the years.)*

The solution is to just point it to the README.md somewhere publicly accessible on the web.  For my pod, I pointed to the raw source of my README at the current version by adding this to my podspec:

```
spec.readme = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/capnslipp/NilCoalescingAssignmentOperators/#{spec.version.to_s}/README.md"
```

I can't say exactly what the URL format will be for a public BitBucket repo, but it should be something similar.  I found this URL on GitHub by clicking on my version tag, then the tag icon to show the whole tree for that version, then clicked on `README.md`, and finally clicked on the Raw button, copied the URL and replaced the version with `#{spec.version.to_s}`.